# how to enter rows of a matrix in r such that each is powers of different number

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I can fill rows of matrix such that the first row is filled with 1 s and the second row with 2 and... the fifth row with 5.
what I m stuck at is how to fill first row with `1^0, 1^1, 1^2 ,...1^10`. then 2nd row with `2^0, 2^1,...2^10` and so on for all 5 rows. 
I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: `outer(1:5, 0:10, '^')`. See the example in `help("outer")`.

Comment: `sapply(0:10, function(x) (1:5) ^ x)` OR `mapply(function(x) (1:5) ^ x, 0:10)`

Answer (score 1):

There is an R function specifically meant for this. ie `poly`:

```
poly(1:5, 10, raw = TRUE)
     1  2   3   4    5     6     7      8       9      10
[1,] 1  1   1   1    1     1     1      1       1       1
[2,] 2  4   8  16   32    64   128    256     512    1024
[3,] 3  9  27  81  243   729  2187   6561   19683   59049
[4,] 4 16  64 256 1024  4096 16384  65536  262144 1048576
[5,] 5 25 125 625 3125 15625 78125 390625 1953125 9765625
```

Of course if you need to raise it by `0` you can just `cbind` the intercept column:

Answer (score 0):

Using `sapply`:

```r
t(sapply(1:5, function(x) x^(0:10)))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]  [,7]  [,8]   [,9]   [,10]   [,11]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1      1       1       1
[2,]    1    2    4    8   16   32    64   128    256     512    1024
[3,]    1    3    9   27   81  243   729  2187   6561   19683   59049
[4,]    1    4   16   64  256 1024  4096 16384  65536  262144 1048576
[5,]    1    5   25  125  625 3125 15625 78125 390625 1953125 9765625
```

This works because R knows how to interpret `x^v` where `v` is a vector:

```r
3^(0:10)
[1]    1     3     9    27    81   243   729  2187  6561 19683 59049
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
t(sapply(1:2,function(x) x^(0:10)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1
[2,]    1    2    4    8   16   32   64  128  256   512  1024
```

Answer (score 0):

```
outer(1:5, 0:10, "^")
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]  [,7]  [,8]   [,9]   [,10]   [,11]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1      1       1       1
# [2,]    1    2    4    8   16   32    64   128    256     512    1024
# [3,]    1    3    9   27   81  243   729  2187   6561   19683   59049
# [4,]    1    4   16   64  256 1024  4096 16384  65536  262144 1048576
# [5,]    1    5   25  125  625 3125 15625 78125 390625 1953125 9765625
```